# He sucks on his fist and making sucking noises

Tags: grammar

> When the baby is hungry, he sucks on his fist and ***making sucking***
>   noises.

Can the 2 verb using present continuos tense?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but it looks like that *making* is supposed to be *makes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When the baby is hungry, he sucks on his fist and making sucking noises.*

This is incorrect. It needs to be either:

*When the baby is hungry, he sucks on his fist, making sucking noises.*

or:

*When the baby is hungry, he sucks on his fist and makes sucking noises*